# updating two arrays to keep track of months and days

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am having hard time updating two arrays - the code below seems to update only update two days.

```
int month[365], day[365];
int countMonths[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

int i = 0;
int currentmonth = 0;
int currentday = 1;
while(i < 365 &&  i < countMonths[currentmonth])
{
    month[i] = currentmonth+1;
    day[i] = currentday;
    i++;
    currentday++;

if(currentday > countMonths[currentmonth]);
   {
    currentmonth++;
    currentday = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `countMonths` store? It looks like it's storing the number of days in each month, but the naming is weird. Also, you might want to remove the semicolon from `if(currentday > countMonths[currentmonth]);`

Comment: @rockonRockOut I've updated the code to show the months.

Comment: You might want `&& currentMonth < 12` in your loop condition, you make sure you don't read an array element that doesn't exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt i changed the logic to `while(i < 365 &&  i < countMonths[currentmonth] && currentmonth < 12)` but the if logic still seems to throw things off and not update my months and days correctly

Comment: Side note: Dealing with calendars is not trivial (you miss leap years)

Comment: @DieterLücking you are correct and I am aware. (alas for this project we are looking at only 2013) not a leap year so in this case it works.

Comment: The test on `currentmonth < 12` needs to go before the access to `countMonths[currentmonth]`.  Like: `while(i < 365 && currentmonth < 12 && i < countMonths[currentmonth])`  Although as @RockOnRockOut noticed, it should be `while(i < 365 && currentmonth < 12 && currentday < countMonths[currentmonth])`.  Or just `while(i < 365 && currentmonth < 12)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have this condition in your while loop: `i < countMonths[currentmonth]` - you stop iterating (because `i` will be 29 and `countMonths[1]` is 28), that's why your month isn't incrementing. Keep only the first condition and you should be good.

Comment: You are my hero. I've been racking my brain all day on this! I can't believe its because of the 29/28 days.

Comment: Lol, glad I could help. I've done similar mistakes in the past (some quite recently) so don't sweat it ;)

Answer (score 2):

On your `if` statement, you have an extra semi-colon

```
if(currentday > countMonths[currentmonth]);
```

You should not have that there.

Comment: Thanks. removing that semi colon definitely fixed one problem but its still showing me - that once i get to month two ... the month inst' incramenting.